# Status update is not working on certain records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a query that updates a status from 'R' released to 'C' closed.

This code works for `subID = 1` and `seqNo = 160`:

```
UPDATE OPERATION 
SET STATUS = 'R'
WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID = 'WO-50903' 
  AND WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = '0' 
  AND WORKORDER_SUB_ID = '0' 
  AND SEQUENCE_NO = '160'
```

This code works for `subID = 1` and `seqNo = 10`

```
UPDATE OPERATION 
SET STATUS = 'R'
WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID = 'WO-50903' 
  AND WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = '0' 
  AND WORKORDER_SUB_ID = '1' 
  AND SEQUENCE_NO = '10'
```

In both these update queries I ran a select of the status with the same where conditions to ensure I was getting the correct record, but with the 2nd update query it doesn't update.

When both update queries run it output that 1 row successfully updated, but although the 2nd update outputs success the value wasn't updated.

Comment: A [mcve] is a must, we need table definitions, sample data and expected results. Otherwise this is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the STATUS needs to be set to C, not R?

Also, the WHERE clause should have a STATUS check so that the update only changes the value if it needs to be changed.  SET STATUS = 'C' ... WHERE STATUS = 'R' ....

If the update query runs without error and indicates 1 record was updated, then it is likely that the update worked.  If a select right after indicates that the Status is not what was set (R or C), I would look at OPERATION in detail.  Is it a view or a table?  Is their a trigger that can change or undo the original update?  Is there a possible transaction rollback before before checking the result of the update?